# Optimizing a DP on Intervals/Points

Tags: algorithm

Well the problem is quite easy to solve naively in O(n<sup>3</sup>) time. The problem is something like:

> There are N unique points on a number line. You want to cover every
>   single point on the number line with some set of intervals. You can
>   place an interval anywhere, and it costs `B + MX` to create an
>   interval, where `B` is the initial cost of creating an interval, and
>   `X` is **half** the length of the interval, and `M` is the cost per
>   length of interval. You want to find the minimum cost to cover every
>   single interval.

Sample data:

```
Points = {0, 7, 100}
B = 20
M = 5
```

So the optimal solution would be 57.50 because you can build an interval [0,7] at cost 20 + 3.5×5 and build an interval at [100,100] at cost 100 + 0×5, which adds up to 57.50.

I have an O(n<sup>3</sup>) solution, where the DP is minimum cost to cover points from `[left, right]`. So the answer would be in `DP[1][N]`. For every pair `(i,j)` I just iterate over `k = {i...j-1}` and compute `DP[i][k] + DP[k + 1][j]`.

However, this solution is O(n<sup>3</sup>) (kind of like matrix multiplication I think) so it's too slow on N > 2000. Any way to optimize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quadratic solution:

1. Sort all the points by coordinate.  Call the points `p`.
2. We'll keep an array `A` such that `A[k]` is the minimum cost to cover the first `k` points.  Set `A[0]` to zero and all other elements to infinity.
3. For each `k` from `0` to `n-1` and for each `l` from `k+1` to `n`, set `A[l] = min(A[l], A[k] + B + M*(p[l-1] - p[k])/2);`

You should be able to convince yourself that, at the end, `A[n]` is the minimum cost to cover all `n` points.  (We considered all possible minimal covering intervals and we did so from "left to right" in a certain sense.)

You can speed this up so that it runs in O(n log n) time; replace step 3 with the following:

Set `A[1] = B`.  For each `k` from `2` to `n`, set `A[k] = A[k-1] + min(M/2 * (p[k-1] - p[k-2]), B)`.

The idea here is that we either extend the previous interval to cover the next point or we end the previous interval at `p[k-2]` and begin a new one at `p[k-1]`.  And the only thing we need to know to make that decision is the distance between the two points.

Notice also that, when computing `A[k]`, I only needed the value of `A[k-1]`.  In particular, you don't need to store the whole array `A`; only its most recent element.

Comment: Also can you explain how you arrived at `O(n log n)` on the complexity for the second solution? Shouldn't it be `O(n)`?

Comment: You still need to sort the input.  That takes more than linear time.